# pgfplots, line in front of marks

Tags: pgfplots

I could not find information on this:  How can I have the line shown *above/in front of* the marker?  Right now it is plotted *behind* the diamond marker in the diagram as well as in the legend.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor, pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[mark=square*, mark options={fill=gray}] coordinates {(1,2)(2,1)};
\legend{x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Actual case with line below marks]

This would be the desired case:

[image: Desired case with line above marks]

Comment: The line is drawn from (1,2) to (2,1). Can you elaborate by How can I have the line shown above the marker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a straightforward part: you can get the plot as desired by using `mark layer`. Just draw the marks on a layer that is behind the main plot. And then there is the part that requires tiny a bit more effort: make the legend comply. To this end, I slightly modified the `legend image code`. (I do not precisely *know* why one has to do this but given that the legend should usually be in front of the plots, it makes sense that the stuff in the legend goes on a different layer, and thus the layer of the mark gets readjusted.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[set layers,mark layer=axis background,
legend image code/.code={
         \draw [mark repeat=2,mark phase=2,#1] plot coordinates {
        (0cm,0cm) (0.3cm,0cm) (0.6cm,0cm)};
        \draw [#1] (0cm,0cm) rectangle (0.5cm,0cm);
    }]
\addplot[mark=square*, mark options={fill=gray}] coordinates {(1,2)(2,1)};
\legend{x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

If you plot the points (but by tikz `\node` and not pgfplot's `mark`) before adding the plot it is easy:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor, pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\node[diamond,fill,color=orange,inner sep=2pt] at (axis cs:1,2) {};
\node[diamond,fill,color=red,inner sep=2pt] at (axis cs:2,1) {};
\node[diamond,fill,color=green,inner sep=2pt] at (axis cs:1.8,1.2) {};
\addplot[thick] coordinates {(1,2)(2,1)};
\legend{x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

PS: I am sure that `pgfplots` has a way too, but I don't really use it, so wait for another answer before accepting because I use mostly `tikz` and no `pgfplots`

[image]

Comment: This is partly what I am looking for.  Within the plot, the line now appears above the markers (even though it is a bit inconvenient not to have only one plot command for this simple line).  However, I as well need to have the line AND symbol in the legend (again, the line overlying the mark).

Comment: @Elmar, I am not using pgfplots and just know some basics on it... I use tikz and creating the legend with tikz commands myself.... So, you can wait for someone that uses pgfplots and can possibly solve completely your problem. I am leaving the answer as it is to help people that possibly will find it usefull